# C#: Retornar valor de a href

Tags: c#, html

Como eu faço para conseguir o endereço/URL de um tag

```
 < a href="js:redir(2)">
```

Através de uma fonte HTML?

OBS: Tentei utilizar o assembly mshtml, mas também não funcionou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar esse [exemplo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9e807fx(v=vs.110).aspx) para implantar no seu projeto, utiliza-se expressão regular.

***C#***

```
private static void DumpHRefs(string inputString)
{
    Match m;
    string HRefPattern = "href\\s*=\\s*(?:[\"'](?<1>[^\"']*)[\"']|(?<1>\\S+))";

    try
    {
         m = Regex.Match(inputString, HRefPattern,
         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled,
         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
         while (m.Success)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
             m = m.NextMatch();
         }
    }
    catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("The matching operation timed out.");
    }
}
```

E para utilizar a função basta enviar o código `HTML` como parâmetro.

***C#***

```
string inputString = "My favorite web sites include:</P>" +
                        "<A HREF=\"http://msdn2.microsoft.com\">" +
                        "MSDN Home Page</A></P>" +
                        "<A HREF=\"http://www.microsoft.com\">" +
                        "Microsoft Corporation Home Page</A></P>" +
                        "<A HREF=\"http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam\">" +
                        ".NET Base Class Library blog</A></P>";

DumpHRefs(inputString);
```

***Resultado***

> http://msdn2.microsoft.com
>
> http://www.microsoft.com
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam

O projeto foi construindo utilizando console, basta adaptar a função ao seu projeto.

***OBS.: Talvez seja necessário incluir a referência abaixo***

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score -1):

Se eu entendi bem o que precisa, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<htmL>
<body>
A url completa da página atual é:
<script>
document.write(document.URL);
</script>

</body>
</html>

document.write(window.location.href)
```

Outras formas:

```
document.write(window.location.protocol) 
document.write(window.location.host) 
document.write(window.location.pathname)
```

O código acima vai exibir:

```
"http"
"teste.com.br"
"login/index.html"
```